# HTACCESS file is not working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 includes/config.php http:/mydomain.com/includes/index.php
Redirect 301 includes/blog_inc.php http://mydomain.com/includes/index.php
```

The problem is that only the first redirect is working which is for a configuration file. I have multiple files to redirect to index.php in this includes folder. What can I do to redirect all requests to  `includes` to `includes/index.php`? I have put this .htaccess file in root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RedirectMatch` for regex use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/includes/(?!index\.php).+$ /includes/index.php
```

Comment: SHould I put it in root directory or includes folder?

Comment: And it is also giving error that The page isn't redirecting properly. I put it in root directory...

Comment: Yes it needs to be in root directory and I fixed the code that was causing looping. Try it now.